# JMeter: how to display Regular Expression Extractor's results in View results in table?

Tags: jmeter

I want to display an extracted value (or, a specified **Default Value**) next to sample information in **View Results in Table** listener, is it possible?

Comment: Use Debug component. Also, you can test your regex expression on response data using ViewResultsTree. Just select Regex tester (or similar, I don't have it in front of me) in lower left corner of ViewResultsTree listener.

Comment: @mbonaci please move your comment to answer so I can close this

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [Debug](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) component.

Also, you can test your regex expression on response data using [ViewResultsTree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree). Just select `Regexp tester` in the drop-down box at the bottom of the left hand panel in your ViewResultsTree listener.

Comment: Not helping!!!
How is it got to do with the *View results in table* as asked?
This question was for the TABLE, not the TREE!

Comment: @ShaiAlon what's with that tone? Like I owe you something? Is it too hard to add `ViewResultsTree` and use it for testing your regex?

Comment: I'm sorry,  @Marco Bonaci. I didn't intend for it to sound like this...
The point was to be able to see the result in the table, without using the tree... Sorry again for the tone :(

Answer (score -3):

Use **ONLY** [Debug sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler).
Place it under the extracted data, and place the extracted value in the Sampler's **Name**.
This will display it in the **View Results Tree**.